# Zend_Paginator let users choose the number of rows per page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I need some conceptual advises with Zend Framework pagination.

I'm using Zend_Paginator that works like a charm, from my view, I'd like a selector for the user to choose how many rows per page (s)he wants, something that will set the parameter of the setItemCountPerPage() method. As of now, I've a hardcoded select form element (that triggers the changing of url with jQuery) in my view that looks like this :

```
   <select id="rpp" name="rpp">
       <option value="/goods">--</option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/2">[2 for dev]</option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/5">5 <?php echo $this->translate('Rows per page') ?></option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/15">15 <?php echo $this->translate('Rows per page') ?></option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/25">25 <?php echo $this->translate('Rows per page') ?></option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/50">50 <?php echo $this->translate('Rows per page') ?></option>
       <option value="/goods/rpp/100">100 <?php echo $this->translate('Rows per page') ?>   </option>
   </select>
```

It works but I'd need this in more than one view, so I tried to make up something in a partial view with something like this :

```
...
<option value="<?php echo $this->userAgent()->getServerValue('request_uri'); ?>/rpp/2">[2 for dev]</option>
...
```

but it ends up with routing troubles in some situations.

What would be a good development strategy, the most generic and re-usable possible for such a feature of letting the user choosing how many rows per page (s)he wants.

Thanks for your advises.

f.

Comment: is there a specific routing problem you wanna solve? if there is, plz add the explanation your question.

Comment: it's not really a problem, but if i use something like "<?php echo $this->userAgent()->getServerValue('request_uri'); ?>/rpp/2" as values for the select element, it's wrongly (correctly of course but not the behaviour i want) populated when the user changes the number of rows per page more than once as the parameters are adding, ending with something like this in the URL : http://my-app/goods/rpp/10/rpp/15/rpp/25 ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Zend_Paginator::setDefaultItemCountPerPage` method and value stored in session in your Bootstrap class to set items per page. If you want to change it later at some stage. Just assign different value to the session variable. For example (**not tested**)

```
protected function _initPagination()
{
  $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('default');
  $itemCountPerPage = (isset($session->itemCountPerPage) 
  ? $session->itemCountPerPage : 5);

  Zend_Paginator::setDefaultItemCountPerPage($itemCountPerPage);
}
```

Later somewhere in your action:

```
public function itemCountPerPageAction()
{
  $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('default');
  $session->itemCountPerPage = $this->_getParam('itemCountPerPage');
  $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit($this->_request->getServer("HTTP_REFERER"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @b.b3rn4rd but my question is more about the view, to have a partial view (or from a view helper?) to avoid refactoring the select element for each pages, so that i don't have to hardcode things like <option value="/goods/rpp/5"> every time. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: @feub Sorry I didn't expand my answer, I thought it might be alternative solution to avoid messing with the url. Basically idea is to have separate action for setting `itemCountPerPage` probably when user selects option in dropdown...